# How to change (re-order) the deltas programmatically in node_presave

Tags: 8

In a node, I have a multi-value field "field_MV" containing 3 items

I don't think it is important, but field_MV  is of type "Entity reference revisions" and the items are paragraphs of only one type.

Each paragraph (item) have a field "field_quantity" containing a number.

Here is my exemple:

```
$node->field_MV[0]->field_quantity->value=5 (paragraph at delta 0)
$node->field_MV[1]->field_quantity->value=3 (paragraph at delta 1)
$node->field_MV[2]->field_quantity->value=7 (paragraph at delta 2)
```

In hook_node_presave, I would like to loop in the paragraphs to change their delta according the the value of field_quantity (descending)

Here is the result I would like to have:

```
$node->field_MV[0]->field_quantity->value=7 (previously paragraph delta 2)
$node->field_MV[1]->field_quantity->value=5 (previously paragraph delta 0)
$node->field_MV[2]->field_quantity->value=3 (previously paragraph delta 1)
```

My question is not how to order (I can handle this), but how to change the delta with something like:

```
$node->field_MV[0]->set("delta",1);
$node->field_MV[0]->save();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would want to set the field value to an array in the order you want them. Since you are doing this inside hook_node_presave, you don't have to bother saving the node. It will be done for you.

Something like this should work:

```
$values = $node->get('field_mv')->getValue();

... your sorting function ...

$node->set('field_mv', $values);
```

Comment: Thank you Chance G, it is working except that I have changed the first line into `$values = $node->field_mv->referencedEntities();` to be able to get an array that I can sort. If you update your answer, I will vote for it.

Comment: I changed it to the generic `getValue()` method. Like most things Drupal, there is more than one way to do things ;)